# Установка парсера через Yarn

Tags: javascript, json, yarn

Существует парсер, который устанавливается через пакетный менеджер yarn. Установка длится второй день. Вопрос: как с yarn или без него запустить данный парсер, так как js что через терминал пк, что через консоль браузера всегда выдает ошибку: `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Mercury'. import call expects exactly one argument.`

---

Для запуска пакета парсера требуется выполнить код, приведенный ниже:

```js
import Mercury from '@postlight/mercury-parser';

Mercury.parse(url).then(result => console.log(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

В каком смысле 2 дня длится? Попробуй npm. Ещё я сталкивался с проблемой, когда с какого-то айпишника не мог что-то из npm установить. Раздал инет с мобилы и всё залетело. Тут бы понять, что ярн говорит.